# jQuery - Scroll into continuous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, web

I guess this is such a jQuery question, please take a look here : http://ueno.co/

Basically, I want to be able to scroll into specific div like this website, how to do that? any tools or open source jQuery to help me to do this?

When user scroll (either up or down) it will tell the browser to scroll into specific point. http://ueno.co/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at plugins like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage). They handle everything.

Comment: oh thank you man!! Been looking for this